# como leer una linea de un txt y autoseguido ir a la proxima linea y guardar ese valor en una variable

Tags: python, txt

a ver para que se me entienda cuento  con este codigo que me da la linea que yo quiera siempre que cambie el valor de i,,donde i es el numero de linea y line es el valor de esa linea,,de esta manera prodria obtener cualquier valor de linea pero tendria que repetir el codigo

```
    with open('PROXY.txt') as ListadoProxy:
       for i, line in enumerate(ListadoProxy, 1):
           if i == 1:
              break
```

supongamos que tenemos este txt ver fig[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo que quiero es poder leer la primera linea y autoseguido saltar a la proxima y leerla dentro del mismo ciclo,,,el codigo que mostre anterior me permite leer la linea que yo quiero pero para poder leer la proxima tendria que repetirlo y cambiar el valor de i,,espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Si no rompes el ciclo con `break` en el condicional en la sigueinte iteración `line` será la siguiente línea sin más...

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer esto tendrías que utilizar `readlines()`. Devuelve una lista  con todas las líneas del archivo.

```
f = open("proxy.txt","r")
while(True):
    linea = f.readline().strip()
    print(linea)
    if not linea:
        break
f.close()
```

Output:

```
157.245.251.117:8080

159.203.44.177:3128

157.245.254.160:8080
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Casi lo tienes, solo algunos detalles:

```
with open('PROXY.txt') as ListadoProxy:
    for i, line in enumerate(ListadoProxy.readlines(), 1):
        line = line.strip()
        print(line)
        if i == 1:
           # Hacemos lo que hay que hacer
        else:
           # hacemos lo que hay que hacer para el resto de las líneas
```

Observaciones:

- Si bien se puede iterar directamente sobre `ListadoProxy` prefiero hacerlo sobre `ListadoProxy.readlines()`
- Lo que es importante saber, es que cada línea leída conserva su salto de línea, por lo que conviene quitarlo para trabajar más cómodamente `line = line.strip()`
- El ciclo de lectura se repetirá hasta finalizar de leer todas las líneas, si dejas el `break` cuando `i == 1` lo finalizarás al leer la primer línea.

Comment: gracias por sus respuestas pero al parecer no me explique bien,,,yo necesito tomar la primera linea,hacer algo(codigo).. y autoseguido saltar a la segunday tomar su valor,pero dentro del mismo ciclo,seria algo como un line+=1,,,

Comment: Pero eso es exactamente lo que hace el ciclo, lee la linea 1, luego la 2 y así, dentro del ciclo tu decides lo que vas a hacer. Cuando preguntas `if i == 1:` estas preguntando si el ciclo está en la linea 1, si es así haces algo sino dejas que de la vuelta a la segunda interación. Revisa mi edición a ver si queda clara la idea.

Answer (score 0):

Si quiere leer el archivo línea por línea, "hacer algo" y entonces pasar a la siguiente línea, mi recomendación es que use [async / await](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

Puesto que quiere que su ciclo (el que lee el archivo línea a línea) espere a que su código "haga algo" con la línea actual antes de pasar a la siguiente.

> Debe importar la librería `asyncio` ya que esta ejecutará su "tarea/función asíncrona"

```
import asyncio

async def processFile():
    file = open('PROXY.txt', 'r')

    for line in file:
        # Aquí el ciclo espera por doSomethingWithLine() antes de
        # pasar a la siguiente iteración
        await doSomethingWithLine(line)

    file.close()

async def doSomethingWithLine(line):
    await asyncio.sleep(1000) # Esperamos un segundo antes de continuar (ilustrativo)
    print(line) # Hacemos "algo" con la línea (imprimirla)

asyncio.run(processFile())
```